# Парсинг div>class Python3

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер

Имею вот такой вот линк

https://yandex.ru/referats/?t=astronomy+geology+gyroscope+literature+marketing+mathematics+music+polit+agrobiologia+law+psychology+geography+physics+philosophy+chemistry+estetica

При заходе на сайт генерируется текст в этом блоке:

```
<div class="referats__text">
<div>Научно-фантастический рассказ</div>
<strong>ТЕМА ЗАГОЛОВОК</strong>
<p>ТЕКСТ1</p>
<p>ТЕКСТ2</p>
</div>
```

Мне нужно спарсить только `<p>`
Подскажите как это сделать

Comment: проблема решена .

Answer (score 0):

Из убунты с python3 работает, сохраняет в файл text.txt фрагменты типа

```
 <p>ТЕКСТ1</p> <p>ТЕКСТ2</p>
```

, виндовс нет проверить из под нее не могу.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from urllib.request import urlopen
url="https://yandex.ru/referats/?t=astronomy+geology+gyroscope+literature+marketing+mathematics+music+polit+agrobiologia+law+psychology+geography+physics+philosophy+chemistry+estetica"
page=urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
page_out=""
oK=False
for one in range(3,len(page)):
    if page[one-3:one]=="<p>": oK=True
    if page[one:one+4]=="</p>": oK=False
    if oK : page_out+=page[one]

f=open('text.txt','w')
f.write(page_out)
f.close()
```

Comment: Для распознавания html лучше html-парсер использовать, вместо прямой манипуляции строк вручную.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы найти текст из всех `<p>` на заданной web-странице, [можно `beautifulsoup4` использовать](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from urllib.request import urlopen 
import bs4  # $  pip install beautifulsoup4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))
paragraphs = [p.get_text() for p in soup.find_all('p')]
```